# mvc4 + jquery mobile + multi page forms best practices

Tags: .net, forms, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

any guidelines or best practices for doing forms in jquerymobile and mvc4 where the form is split across several pages? Jqm allows setting several divs in one html doc as "pages", but with forms I'm imaginging data validation etc to be a headache going this route?

Answer (score 1):

I have spent the past few months exploring jQuery Mobile on top of asp.net, both web forms and mvc. First, and I realize it is not part of your question, jQM and web forms and the postback model is fundamentally broken. The only approach with web forms it to turn off ajax loading in jQM's mobileinit. I recently completed small site consisting of 4 or 5 pages that needed to be deployed on top of web forms. I wound up going with a single html file that contained the 4 or 5 "pages" / `<div data-role="page">` elements. All data interchange was accomplished via ASMX service calls. Some JavaScript and KnockoutJS. It worked fine but was overly complicated for such a simple site.

As for mvc, the jQM model and its ajax implementation works fine. Mixing single and multi page templates works ok but you need to have clear delineations between different areas of your app. I played with this latter approach and in the end, moved to single page templates mainly because it was the most consistant approach with my current mvc development experience. I also explored a complete SPA approach but abandoned it in the end since it wasn't a requirement and significantly complicated my efforts.

The only item I continue to struggle with a bit is that most users given a mobile experience expect all data to be saved on a page when you navigate off of it via any link. If you have standard form `submit` buttons alone with additional nav buttons that are likely outside of your `form`, you will need to invoke some type of javascript / ajax to insure your form gets submitted. And remember that your nav buttons are likely in the footer and outside of your form.

In general, I remain extremely excited about the possibilities around jQM and mvc. If I can make a career out of nothing but these, I will a happy camper. There are not a lot of great end to end examples out there of jQM and MVC. If you would like to chat more on this, I would be happy to. I clearly don't have all the answers but have experienced a bit of pain and can steer you away from a few approaches.

Comment: Thansk for the answer. MVC does seem like a good fit with jqm when doing a single form per page type of app. What I'm wondering is for more complex operations, if there are any specific tools to help generate this code from a model and squeze teh best practices into it- think of scaffolding, but where you can define multuple pages of a form, and have ajax do partial saves as you go. 
Right now I have a long form on a single page, which does both client and server validation. I can add the basiic data-role="page" to this and split itup, but I'm guess ing server validation will get messy then?

Comment: I had good luck with KnockoutJS on top of a multi-page form and used ajax to read and write data back to the server.